# How to fade between define colors with a dependent variable returning UIColor

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, uicolor, nsdatecomponents

I want to create a function, in a format shown in the code below, to fade between defined colors. The purpose of this function is to change the color of the table view cell depending on when the data was created; NSDate. This function should only consider the time of a day; 2015-07-07T12:00:00 will have the same color as 2015-07-06T12:00:00.

```
@implementation NSDate (COLOR_)

- (UIColor *)dayNightColorByTimeOfDay {

}

@end
```

The colors i want to "fade" between are these:

- 12a #0525FF
- 6a #FFF199
- 12p #FFD005
- 6p #059CFF
- and then back to 12a.

An example would be a date passed into the function, dateValue = 3pm, would return the color between the two colors, 12p and 6p. I don't want it to animate.

Each cell in the table represents an instance of this array:

```
array {
  ...
  NSString title,
  NSDate date
  ...
};
```

The data in **array.date** is always set to **[NSDate date]**. As you could tell by now self, a data type of NSDate, is the defendant variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer contains a few ideas.  First is interpolation of colors.  RGB representation can be interpolated fairly simply by interpolating the components, like this:

```
// take two bounding colors and answer one that is pct distance between them
- (UIColor *)colorBetween:(UIColor *)colorA and:(UIColor *)colorB distance:(CGFloat)pct {
    CGFloat aR, aG, aB, aA;
    [colorA getRed:&aR green:&aG blue:&aB alpha:&aA];

    CGFloat bR, bG, bB, bA;
    [colorB getRed:&bR green:&bG blue:&bB alpha:&bA];

    CGFloat rR = (1.0-pct)*aR + pct*bR;
    CGFloat rG = (1.0-pct)*aG + pct*bG;
    CGFloat rB = (1.0-pct)*aB + pct*bB;
    CGFloat rA = (1.0-pct)*aA + pct*bA;

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:rR green:rG blue:rB alpha:rA];
}
```

We also need to interpolate times, which can be done approximately by representing times as minutes past midnight...

```
- (NSInteger)minutesSinceMidnightOfDate:(NSDate *)date {

    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSIntegerMax fromDate:date];
    [components setHour:0];
    [components setMinute:0];
    [components setSecond:0];

    NSDate *midnight = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];

    NSDateComponents *diff = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:midnight toDate:date options:0];

    return [diff minute];
}
```

We need to represent the parameters for the interpolation, done here as directly as possible from those given in the question...

```
// macro to convert hex value to UIColor
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) \
    [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
                    green:((float)((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >>  8))/255.0 \
                     blue:((float)((rgbValue & 0x0000FF) >>  0))/255.0 \
                    alpha:1.0]
```

Now, to do the work, find the times (in minutes past midnight) before and after a given time, get the colors corresponding to those times, interpolate the colors with a proportion matching the temporal distance between the before and after times.

```
- (UIColor *)colorForDate:(NSDate *)date {
    // look up the bounds of interpolation here
    NSArray *wheel = @[ @[ @0,    UIColorFromRGB(0x0525FF) ],
                        @[ @360,  UIColorFromRGB(0xFFF199) ],
                        @[ @720,  UIColorFromRGB(0xFFD005) ],
                        @[ @1080, UIColorFromRGB(0x059CFF) ],
                        @[ @1440, UIColorFromRGB(0x0525FF) ]];

    NSInteger m = [self minutesSinceMidnightOfDate:date];

    // find the index in wheel where the minute bound exceeds our date's minutes (m)
    NSInteger wheelIndex = 0;
    for (NSArray *pair in wheel) {
        NSInteger timePosition = [pair[0] intValue];
        if (m < timePosition) {
            break;
        }
        wheelIndex++;
    }

    // wheelIndex will always be in 1..4, get the pair of bounds at wheelIndex
    // and the preceding pair (-1).
    NSArray *priorPair = wheel[wheelIndex-1];
    NSArray *pair = wheel[wheelIndex];

    CGFloat priorMinutes = [priorPair[0] intValue];
    CGFloat minutes = [pair[0] intValue];

    // this is how far we are between the bounds pairs
    CGFloat minutesPct = ((float)m - priorMinutes) / (minutes - priorMinutes);

    // and the colors for the bounds pair
    UIColor *priorColor = priorPair[1];
    UIColor *color = pair[1];

    // call the color interpolation
    return [self colorBetween:priorColor and:color distance:minutesPct];
}
```

Comment: This is outstanding! Will I be able to modify the declaration, **NSArray *wheel = ..** with any other hex, or any number of pairs? Like if i wanted to add more define colors of the day.

Comment: Sure. So long as the first time value is 0 and the last is 1440.